# Multiprocessing is not achieved

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing in python for running 10-20 input files which are in xml format together  using parallel process which can be achieved by multiprocessing. But when i try to run the code

```
service = Process(name='my_service', target=function_name, args=(run_xml, result_dest,))    
service.start()
```

I get pickling error when i tried to run the code and can any one suggest me the possible solution?

f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "D:\Program Files\Aon\PathWise 2.0\apps\py_vendors\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
**pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not found as __main__.new**

Comment: Hi Ravi, two questions in very short time without giving the **exact** and **verbatim** error code is making it hard to help you. Please provide good error information. Click on the "edit" button below your question and add the **full, copy&pasted, code-formatted** error that python gives you.

Comment: Also ravi you will get more help and more quickly if you follow [this guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for making a minimum, complete, verifiable example.